# how to display the php array in json format in ajax php codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have couple of errors

```js
$errors = array();
$errors['failed'] = "File uplaoded failed Please correct the following error";
$errors['size'] = 'File size must be 100 MB';
$errors['ext'] = "This formate does not support, Only .zip supported";
$errors['exits'] = "Sorry, file name already exists ,Please enter another theme name";
echo json_encode($errors)
```

```js
$(function() {
     $('#addTheme').submit(function(e) {         
               e.preventDefault(); //ok
               var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
              $.ajax({
                 url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>download/uploaded',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: data,
                 dataType : 'json',
                 contentType: false,
                 cache: false,
                 processData: false,

                 success : function(response) {
                     $('.populate').val('');
                   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));
                   if(obj.value === 1) {
                     $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+'File uploaded successfully</div>');
                 } else {
                    $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+'File uploaded failed'+   +'</div>');
                 }
                 console.log("upload success");
            },
        });
             
             

         });     
 });
```

i want to display the errors in ajax, i have the above code, how could i display the error in ajax using json. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var obj = response;`

Comment: @splash what is this mean

Comment: i want to display the error in else part

Comment: why do you not join the array with `<br>` in php?

Comment: i got an answer an, it displayed it below

Comment: in php `implode('<br', $errors);` and sent this string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var items=[];
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
items.push(value);
});
```

since it is an associative array, it will display all the error.